# Is it possible to download all photos that are tagged with a specific user?

Tags: facebook

I got married over the weekend and since I wasn't able to snap pics of myself, many of our friends did. There are just too many photos to save so I figure let's use some PHP magic to download the photos that are tagged with my name. Is this possible?

Let me clarify, I'm not interested in making an app of any sort. Preferably, if I could use curl to grab all photos, that would suffice. Everything I've read thus far says I need to sign up as a developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the photos with graph api. Source: [Graph API User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). The photos option provides all the photo owned by you or in which you are tagged in.

You still need to register an app with facebook for this. Registering an app is inevitable. It is up to you if you want to make it public. You need api_key and api_secret to access privilege on user's "private" information.

You can get it done by an account who is registered developer or register yourself as an developer.

To register yourself as a developer you need to share either your contact no. or credit card no. I have been registered with facebook as a developer but i have never had problems with the privacy.

Comment: Right but would I still need to signup and create an app? This would be for my use only and no one else.